# Remove title in biblatex references

Tags: biblatex

I want to cite articles as full reference, but only in the text. So far, everything works in the MWE below, but there is still the title of the article which I want to suppress.

One way I found to do this was by adding `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{}`; but that cancels the title *and* leaves two commas (`,,`) where the title has been.

Another suggestion was to use `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{title}}`, but that doesn't seem to work at all.

Does anyone know how to get rid of the title? Such that the citations become

> I want to cite Author et al. (2050), *Journal A*, **50**, 63–90 as well as Author (2013), *Journal B*, **50**, 63–90

Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% THE REFERENCES %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{entry1,
  author =   {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and Cusor, C.},
  title =    {Title A},   
  journal =      {Journal A},   
  volume =       {50},
  year =       {2050},
  pages =    {63--90},
}
@article{entry2,
  author =   {Author, A.},
  title =    {Title of Article B},
  journal =      {Journal B},   
  volume =       {50},
  year =       {2013},
  pages =    {63--90},
}
\end{filecontents}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% BIBLIOGRAPHY STYLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxnames=1,backend=bibtex,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibemph{#1},} % italic journal title 
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
%\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{} % remove title
\renewbibmacro{in:}{} % remove "in"
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{} % remove first name
\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{, }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% BEGIN THE DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
I want to cite
\fullcite{entry1}
as well as
\fullcite{entry2}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{title}}`. `title` is a `field` not a `list`. But it is not a good idea to not display the `title`, I think (see the comments to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/138981/35864)). `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{}` is not really something one should do, as `biblatex` still *thinks* it prints the title even though it did in fact not do that.

Comment: @moewe No, that doesn't work, but I just found a solution. It seems one needs to redefine the "Driver", i.e. `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{\printnames{author}
  \newunit
 
  \printfield{year}
 
  \newunit
 
  \printfield{journaltitle}
 
  \newunit
 
  \printfield{volume}
 
  \newunit
 
  \printfield{pages}
 
  \finentry}`

Comment: Weird it works for me... Just to reiterate: You want to use `\fullcite` with title and `\printbibliography` without? If you want `\fullcite` to ignore the title, go with `\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{title}}`. Please do not redefine the driver in such a minimal way.

Comment: @moewe hm strange, now it seems to work as you wrote. Not sure what I did wrong before. And I want to only cite the articles in the text, but with full reference and not have `\printbibliography` at all

Comment: @moewe: there seems to be some extra space before the citations, particularly visible if I do `(\fullcite{entry1})`. Do you know how to get rid of that?

Comment: That's due to the way you suppress the first name: `\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{}` is really not a good idea for (just as I explained about `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{}` above). You could try `\DeclareNameFormat{first-last}{\iffirstinits{\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{}{#5}{#7}}{\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{}{#5}{#7}}\usebibmacro{name:andothers}}` instead (probably not the best solution, but the best I could come up with).

Comment: not quite sure how that works, but it does the trick! Thank you so much! I have spend most of today fighting with this.

Comment: On second thoughts, `\DeclareNameFormat{first-last}{\usebibmacro{name:last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}\usebibmacro{name:andother‌​s}}` might even be better.

Answer (score 25):

**One should not suppress fields with `\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{}`**, since `biblatex` could still think it printed the `title`, even though it really did not do that. This can result in superfluous and spurious spaces and punctuation - although there are measures to prevent this. Indeed the tactics of using `\DeclareFieldFormat{<field>}{}` to suppress a field seems to work without issues in many circumstances, but only because `biblatex` works frantically in the background cleaning up unwanted double punctuation. In the MWE this was not really possible because of `\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{, }` (`\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}` would have worked).

If you want to get rid of the `title` information in a citation, go with

```
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{title}}
```

to delete the information in the bibliography, it is

```
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{title}}
```

There are more radical solutions to remove the title in a way that it gets never passed to `biblatex` in the first place with

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=title, null]
    }
  }
}
```

or in a way that suppresses the title when it is read from the `.bbl` with

```
\DeclareFieldInputHandler{title}{\def\NewValue{}}
```

If you don't want to use the title in your document at all, the radical solutions are slightly more elegant.

Similarly, `\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{}` is not the best idea to suppress first names, you might try

```
\DeclareNameFormat{first-last}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
  \usebibma‌​cro{name:andother‌​s}}
```

here (see also [Biblatex: Last name only in \footcite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/165481/35864) for other solutions).

Comment: How can I remove the title for only one type of entry, like articles? `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{}` works fine for that end, but is not the elegant choice as you write. But the other options you list all work globally.

Comment: @And In `\AtEveryCitekey` and `\AtEveryBibitem` you can use `\ifentrytype{article}{<true>}{<false>}` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52601/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40097/35864). In `\DeclareSourcemap` you can use `\pertype` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229428/35864). For `\DeclareFieldInputHandler` you need some more work (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/410384/35864).