# Biblatex: Last name only in \footcite

Tags: biblatex

How can I drop the authors first name in the following MWE? I have already suppressed the volume and pages of the entry. I just want this to read:

Brav and Heaton (2002). Competing Theories of Financial Anomalies. Reveiw of Financial Studies.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begingroup\newif\ifmy
\IfFileExists{\jobname.bib}{}{\mytrue}
\ifmy
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Brav2002,
author = {Alon Brav and J. B. Heaton},
title = {Competing Theories of Financial Anomalies},
journal = {Reveiw of Financial Studies},
year = {2002},
volume = {15:2},
pages = {575-606},
owner = {User},
timestamp = {2013.11.03}
}
\end{filecontents}
\fi\endgroup

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,citestyle=verbose]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{delete.bib}


\renewbibmacro{in:}{\hspace{-5pt}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{pages}\clearfield{volume}}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Stuff famous linguists asked}
\begin{block}{A block}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Is it part?\footcite{Brav2002}
\item More Saussure.
\end{enumerate}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `\DeclareNameFormat` directive to throw away the first names. I just added the following line to your code

```
\DeclareNameFormat{}{\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{}{#5}{#1}{#7}}
```

which just omits the output of first names, as you can see in the sample page below:

[image]

I have to admit it is in some parts a bit of a hacky solution as it just abuses the `name:first-last` bibmacro and I also did not check if it deals with name suffixes and prefixes correctly, but it works in the environment of your MWE.

Comment: This will go awry if `biblatex` needs to add an "et al." (it will just be eaten up), better use something like `\DeclareNameFormat{}{\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{}{#5}{#1}{#7}\usebibmacro{name:andothers}}`. (Plus, I'm not even sure whether one should use `\DeclareNameFormat` with an empty first argument. There is also a `bibmacro{name:last}`.)

Comment: As written it's some hackish solution and I didn't think much about and also kept my research about the possible `bibmacro`s rather short.

Answer (score 7):

I'd suggest using the following redefinition of `cite:full`:

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{labelname}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}
```

`cite:full` in the `verbose` styles normally just prints the whole bibliography entry as it would be printed in the bibliography, but before that it changes `sortname` to `default` (`\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}`), so we get names in `first-last` format (as that is what `default` is set to ... by default).

We simply change `sortname` to `labelname`, so we get last names if possible and unambiguous names otherwise (depending on the `uniqeuname` option; anyway, the name format will be the same as in subsequent citations).

---

If you insist on last names no matter what, I'd suggest

```
\DeclareNameFormat{family}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}
```

*Edited for the [new name format in `biblatex` >= 3.3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864), see edit history for pre-3.3 code.*

---

MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Brav2002,
  author = {Alon Brav and J. B. Heaton},
  title = {Competing Theories of Financial Anomalies},
  journal = {Reveiw of Financial Studies},
  year = {2002},
  volume = {15:2},
  pages = {575-606},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=verbose]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\renewbibmacro{in:}{\hspace{-5pt}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{pages}\clearfield{volume}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{labelname}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Stuff famous linguists asked}
\begin{block}{A block}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Is it part?\footcite{Brav2002}
\item More Saussure.\footcite{Brav2002}
\end{enumerate}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, great answer, since this answers a few years old, could I inquire whether the `usebibmacro{name:last}` which in some way I think has been replaced with `usebibmacro{name:family}` still works?  I think the arguments it takes must have changed, because as is, it results in `Illegal parameter number in definition of \blx@defformat@d`

Comment: @EngBIRD You will need something like `\DeclareNameFormat{family}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}` (modulo line breaks). See above.

Comment: Very nice, but it's worth noting that your declaration of `cite:full` should go in the `.cbx`-file properly specified with `citestyle=`... Your solution is neat, but it took me many long hours to figure out how to apply it :/

Comment: @nJGL The code can just be added to the preamble as in the MWE at the end. (I just verified that the MWE indeed compiles as expected.) You should not (have to) modify system-installed `.cbx` files.