# Authors' last names in footnote citation, but full citation (first and last name) in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I am working with biblatex and verbose-inote style to include references in footnote citations in addition to the full bibliography at the end of the document.

I would like to shorten the footnote citation to include only the authors' last name(s), but print the full citation (first and last name(s)) in the bibliography at the very end of the document.

I came across this question ([Biblatex: Last name only in \footcite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165481/biblatex-last-name-only-in-footcite)), on how to modify the footnote citation command as to include the last names only, yet, it will equally change the bibliography entry to include the last name only.

My MWE is:

```
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@article{Arzheimer.2006,
 author = {Arzheimer, Kai and Carter, Elisabeth},
 year = {2006},
 title = {{P}olitical {O}pportunity {S}tructures and {R}ight-{W}ing {E}xtremist {P}arty {S}uccess},
 pages = {419--443},
 volume = {45},
 journaltitle = {European Journal of Political Research}, shortjournal =   {EJPR}, 
 number = {3},
 shorttitle = {Political Opportunity Structures}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex, citestyle=verbose-inote, bibstyle=authortitle, autocite=footnote, isbn=false, doi=false, citepages=suppress, parentracker=false, dashed=false, sorting=nyt, maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=5]{biblatex} 

\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}


% Commas as separators
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

% NO `in:' BEFORE JOURNALTITLE 
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

\usepackage{xpatch}
% Comma before issue + date
\xpatchbibmacro{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}}%
{\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}}%
{}{}

% No dot before number of articles
\xpatchbibmacro{volume+number+eid}{%
  \setunit*{\adddot}%
}{%
}{}{}
% Number of articles in parentheses
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

% Comma before and after journal volume
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}% NEW
  \printfield{volume}%
% \setunit*{\adddot}% DELETED
  %\setunit*{\addcomma\space}% NEW
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

% Comma before date; date not in parentheses
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}% NEW
% \printtext[parens]{% DELETED
    \iffieldundef{issue}
      {\usebibmacro{date}}
      {\printfield{issue}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
% \usebibmacro{date}}}% DELETED
       \usebibmacro{date}}% NEW
  \newunit}

%Include shortjournal, journal abbreviation
\renewbibmacro*{journal}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifcitation} and not test     {\iffieldundef{shortjournal}} }
{\printfield[journaltitle]{shortjournal}}
{\iffieldundef{journaltitle}
   {}
   {\printtext[journaltitle]{%
      \printfield[titlecase]{journaltitle}%
      \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
      \printfield[titlecase]{journalsubtitle}}}}}



\bibliography{bib}  
\begin{document}

This is supposed to print only the authors' last names\autocite{Arzheimer.2006}. Whereas the bibliography should keep the full citation. 

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Authors' last names in footnote citation.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer from [moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165524/2693) can be adapted to the `verbose-inote` style.  Just add the following to your preamble:

```
\renewbibmacro*{footcite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{labelname}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}
```

This will use disambiguated last names; if you want to force last names no matter what, then you will need to add the code defined there for the name format.