# Shortened citation in footnote and full citation in bibliography at the end

Tags: beamer, biblatex, footnotes, biber

In a `beamer` presentation, I would like to have short citations in the footnotes and full citations in the bibliography shown at the very end of the presentation. The format of the short citations should be such that for books, it only includes *second name, book-title, year*, e.g.

Smith, *A book title* (2018)

I managed to suppress the first names by using the example from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258125/authors-last-names-in-footnote-citation-but-full-citation-first-and-last-name), where it is suggested to use the the `verbose-inid` style. But how to avoid the `publisher` and `year` information?

Here is my example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\begin{filecontents*}{test_bib.bib} 
    @book{Peter1, 
        author={Peter Muller}, 
        title={My life as Peter Mueller}, 
        address={Peterstown}, 
        publisher={Petersen family},
        year={2017}
    } 
    @book{Uwe1, 
        author={Uwe Ha}, 
        title={Notes about Peter Mueller}, 
        address={Chicago}, 
        publisher={Worldclass Publisher},
        year={2008}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[
    style=verbose-inote,
    autocite=footnote,
    backend=biber,
    ]
    {biblatex}
\addbibresource{test_bib.bib}

% code from linked question
\renewbibmacro*{footcite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{labelname}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Two columns on this page}
    \begin{columns}[T]
        \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
          \begin{itemize}
              \item Some text in the first column
              \item More text\footnotemark
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \footcitetext{Peter1}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Guess what: more text\footnotemark
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    \footcitetext{Uwe1}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Bibliography}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I am compiling with `xelatex biber xelatex xelatex`.

**Edit**: the difference to the linked question is that I also want to *remove* parts of the citation (publisher and city in this case) and not add something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Beamer: How to add "Year" information to footcite?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389665/beamer-how-to-add-year-information-to-footcite)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the style `authortitle` and renew the `bibmacro` that prints the title:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\begin{filecontents*}{test_bib.bib}
    @book{Peter1,
        author={Peter Muller},
        title={My life as Peter Mueller},
        address={Peterstown},
        publisher={Petersen family},
        year={2017}
    }
    @book{Uwe1,
        author={Uwe Ha},
        title={Notes about Peter Mueller},
        address={Chicago},
        publisher={Worldclass Publisher},
        year={2008}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=authortitle,
            autocite=footnote,
            backend=biber,
           ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test_bib.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
    \setunit{\space}%
    \printtext[parens]{\printdate}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Two columns on this page}
    \begin{columns}[T]
        \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
          \begin{itemize}
              \item Some text in the first column
              \item More text\footnotemark
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \footcitetext{Peter1}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Guess what: more text\footnotemark
                \item Both \footnotemark
              \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    \footcitetext{Uwe1}
    \footcitetext{Uwe1,Peter1}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Bibliography}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, that solved my problem! As an addition question, is there a nice reference where I can learn about the stuff happening in `renewbibmacro` ?

Comment: @Alf This very [site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=renewbibmacro) is a good reference, try https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191204/trying-to-understand-the-renewbibmacro-and-declarefieldformat-construct