# Removing title from citation of a translated article in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

[A previous answer shows how to remove the title for presumably all citations in a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165732/9945). Unfortunately `\clearfield{title}` does not work for the titles of translated articles. `\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{}` does work, however, but for reasons specified in the previous answer it is not an ideal solution due to extra punctuation.

Here is a minimum working example. Note that the Russian title is kept but the English translation's title is not.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{skrebkov_turbulentnyye_1963,
  title = {Turbulentnyye pul'satsii v zhidkoy struye i yeye raspylivaniye},
  issn = {0869-5032},
  url = {http://www.sibran.ru/journals/issue.php?ID=160175&ARTICLE_ID=160248},
  number = {3},
  journaltitle = {Prikladnaya mekhanika i tekhnicheskaya fizika},
  author = {Skrebkov, G. P.},
  date = {1963-05},
  pages = {79--83}
}

@article{skrebkov_turbulent_1966,
  title = {Turbulent {{Pulsations}} in a {{Liquid Jet}}, and {{Its Atomization}}},
  url = {http://www.dtic.mil/docs/citations/AD0635269},
  number = {3},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Applied Mechanics and Technical Physics (Foreign Technology Division)},
  author = {Skrebkov, G. P.},
  date = {1966-02-16},
  pages = {142--151},
  related = {skrebkov_turbulentnyye_1963},
  relatedtype = {translationof}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{title}}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

\begin{document}
\nocite{skrebkov_turbulent_1966}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: minimum working example]

Additionally, if anyone knows how to remove the extraneous period in "Trans. of.", I'd be appreciative.

Comment: I don't see the incorrect full stop with `biblatex` 3.10. What version are you using?

Comment: 2.7 on this computer. I tried my laptop, which had a more recent version and the incorrect period was absent. Thanks for the reminder to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
\DeclareFieldInputHandler{title}{\def\NewValue{}}
```

or

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=title, null]
    }
  }
}
```

to get rid of the `title` field more effectively.

The first causes `biblatex` to never read the `title` from the `.bbl`, while the second causes Biber to discard the `title` when reading the `.bib` file, so that it does not even appear in the `.bbl`.

`\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{title}}` on the other hand, creates a hook that is executed whenever a bibliography item is printed. It then temporarily deletes the `title`. The title of the translation is not deleted since it belongs to a different entry. But the hook is not executed again when the related entry is processed.

The source mapping approach can also be restricted to certain types only

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{article}
      \step[fieldset=title, null]
    }
  }
}
```

It is also possible to restrict `\DeclareFieldnputHandler` by type, but that needs a slight change of some internal macros at the moment

```
\makeatletter
\protected\def\blx@bbl@entry#1#2#3{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\abx@field@entrykey{\detokenize{#1}}%
  \blx@setoptions@type{#2}%
  \blx@bbl@options{#3}%
  \blx@setoptions@entry
  \edef\blx@bbl@data{blx@data@\the\c@refsection @\blx@dlist@name @\abx@field@entrykey}%
  \blx@bbl@addfield{entrykey}{\abx@field@entrykey}%
  \listxadd\blx@entries{\abx@field@entrykey}%
  \blx@bbl@addfield{entrytype}{#2}%
  \csuse\blx@bbl@data
  \blx@imc@iffieldundef{options}
    {}
    {\blx@bbl@fieldedef{options}{\expandonce\abx@field@options}}}

\DeclareFieldInputHandler{title}{\ifentrytype{article}{\def\NewValue{}}{}}
\makeatother
```

If the change is entirely unproblematic I might submit a pull request to get this into the `biblatex` core.

Comment: Thanks, this works. One problem I forgot to specify in the question, however. Is it possible to make this apply only to articles, conference proceedings, and chapters? I want to keep the titles for books and reports. I tried `\DeclareFieldInputHandler{title}{\ifentrytype{article}{\def\NewValue{}}{}}` but this does not seem to work. I do not have a clear understanding of what is occurring under the hood, unfortunately.

Comment: Works perfectly now. Many thanks. I learned a few things from this.