# How to omit address field while using biblatex

Tags: biblatex, xetex

Its possible to omit url by

```
url=false
```

How to omit `address`?

I tried `address=false` but its not that.

Just found:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=address, null]
      \step[fieldset=editor, null]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `url=no` should not work. The option is a boolean option and accepts the values `true` and `false`. The `\DeclareSourcemap` is pretty much what I would use, but you need to keep in mind that `address` is an alias for `location`, so you probably want to clear both `address` and `location`.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141822/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32930/35864

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least with the standard styles

```
url=no,
```

is not valid and will produce an error along the lines of

```
! Package etoolbox Error: Invalid boolean value 'no'.
```

`url` is a boolean option and can only take the values `true` or `false` (it can also appear without a value, which is equivalent to passing the value `true`).

Contrary to a belief held by some that pops up from time to time in various LaTeX forums and also on this site, this does not work for all fields. In fact only `url`, `isbn` (and with it `issn` and `isrn`), `eprint` and the `related` fields can be suppressed in this way. All other fields need to be gotten rid of with different methods.

---

There are two things to keep in mind when dealing with `address`.

1. `address` is actually only a convenience alias for backwards compatibility with BibTeX. The field is remapped to the field `location` by Biber. Internally `biblatex` only knows `location` and not `address`.
2. `biblatex` distinguishes three types of fields. Name lists, lists and (proper) fields. If you want to clear a 'field' with `\clear...` you need to know its type and need to use the corresponding `\clear...` command (`\clearfield`, `\clearlist`, `\clearname`). `location` is a list. You can find out the type of each field known to `biblatex` by consulting the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), specifically §2.2 *Entry Fields*.

There are several ways to get rid of a field.

---

My preferred way to completely get rid of `address`/`location` would be via a Biber sourcemap. Sourcemaps are executed before the field aliases are applied, so before `address` is remapped to `location`. Hence, we need to to `null` both `address` and `location` to make sure the `address`/`location` is gone.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=address, null]
      \step[fieldset=location, null]
    }
  }
}
```

This method completely removes all traces of the field. The field will not be used by Biber to calculate any of the advanced features like name uniqueness, label... fields etc. and it will not be passed on to `biblatex`.

---

A slightly less pretty method to remove `location` would involve

```
\DeclareListInputHandler{location}{\def\NewValue{}}
```

Biber will still see the field and might take it into account for its calculations, but `biblatex` will simply ignore it.

---

Finally, you can selectively suppress the fields in citations or the bibliography with

```
 \AtEveryCitekey{\clearlist{location}}
 \AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{location}}
```

That way the data has been processed by Biber and could have been used for label and uniqueness calculations; it is  also in principle known to `biblatex`, but you tell it to forget about it for the time being.

---

In general I would say it is good advice to ignore a field as early as possible (especially if we are talking about name or date fields), but for most intents and purposes involving `location`/`address` the three methods will give the same results.

Comment: Sir, my mistake saying `url=no`, I took that from my mind without checking code. I should have said `url=false`. Updated question. Although, I will took the opportunity to ask, will there be any disadvantage in having `yes/no`functioning as `true/false`, or even `1/0`?

Comment: @KcFnMi Well, the only real disadvantage that I could think about is that someone has to do the work to make `yes/no` or `1/0` work. Currently `biblatex` just delegates that work to `etoolbox` and need not do any of the work to pre-process other truthy or falsy values. One might also try to argue that more values could be more confusing, but that probably does not hold a lot of water.

Comment: It has not been implemented because no one has asked for it yet and if someone were to ask for it at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues now I would probably not be too keen on it, since `true`/`false` is established, works well enough and I see no compelling reason why adding something like `yes`/`no` would bring a huge benefit. But if enough people say it is needed we can always look into it.