# De-Italicise Volume Numbers in Bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I've just started using biblatex and biber to compile my bibliographies. Everything is great, except I'm having two problems: (1) I want to get rid of the issue number for journal articles; and (2) I don't want the volume number for journal articles to be in italics.

I've found a solution to the first problem, I just have to have the following command in the preamble:

`\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{number}}`

My question is: is there a similarly simple fix for de-italicising the volume numbers?

Thanks for the help!

(I use Mendeley as my reference manager, so I can't mess around with my .bib file)

Here's a MWE:

```
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[style=apa, natbib=true, doi=false, url=false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{/Users/James/Documents/library.bib}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{number}}
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep}

\title{Customising My Bibliography}
\date{\vspace{-8ex}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\noindent Hello, I want to cite \citet{Steinberger2016, Steinberger2019b} without the volume number in the bibliography being italicised.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And here's what it outputs:

[image]

Comment: Normally (that is to say with the `biblatex` standard styles and no additional configuration) the volume is not italicised. So either there is some manual markup in your `.bib` file or you use a style that italicises the `volume`. Please show us a short example document (an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that reproduces what you are seeing at the moment so we can see what is going on and so we can suggest a suitable solution.

Comment: Hi, I've added a MWE to my original question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: For future reference I'd like to mention that the code posted in the question is not an MWE: It is missing a `\documentclass`, so if we copy and paste it into an empty document the code will not run as expected. It also calls a file `/Users/James/Documents/library.bib` that we don't have. If you need specific entries from your `.bib` file, please post them here as well. If you can live with generic entries from `biblatex-examples.bib`, use that (see the MWE in my answer). (The MWE was also not completely minimal, since it loads packages like `ebgaramond` that aren't needed, but that is OK.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`biblatex-apa` implements the guidelines of the APA publication manual as closely as possible with `biblatex`. One of the aspects of APA style is that the volume number should be set in italics.

It is fairly simple to change that with a `\DeclareFieldFormat` declaration, but this is a hint that maybe you shouldn't be using `biblatex-apa`. Since `biblatex-apa` was specifically designed to implement the complex guidelines of APA style, it is not as flexible and easily customisable as other `biblatex` styles (notably the standard styles are much more customisable). That's why it is usually a bad idea to use `biblatex-apa` if you want a style that is not APA.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa, natbib=true, doi=false, url=false]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\apanum{#1}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\parencite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson, E. & Ryde, U. (1998). Comparison of methods for deriving atomic harges from the electrostatic potential and moments. Journal of Computational Chemistry, 19(4), 377–395.]

---

My preferred way to suppress the `number` field would be

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=number, null]
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatives and more details are discussed at [How to omit address field while using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/491887/35864), [Is it possible to suppress a specific field from bibtex .bbl in biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32930/35864), [Remove title in biblatex references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141822/35864),

Comment: Thanks so much, super helpful!!