# Remove publisher's address from references, Chicago style

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

I am using the Chicago author/title footnote referencing system and would like to remove the publisher's address both from footnotes and bibliography (but without removing it from my library.) Here is the code:

```
\usepackage[notes,backend=biber,hyperref=false,giveninits=true]{biblatex-chicago}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{month}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{address}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{address}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{doi}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{doi}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{url}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{url}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{issn}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{issn}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{isbn}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{isbn}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{number}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{number}}
```

The command `\AtEveryBibitem` and `\AtEveryCitekey` works for every other field indicated above, except the address.

Comment: It would help if you showed the code of a small document that gives the complete setup, and also showed a bib entry with an address that you want to suppress. Since you clear the `address` field: where do you put the publisher's address? Most people put it into the `publisher` field. Then it is difficult to split the information in this field.

Comment: Use `\clearlist{address}` instead

Comment: Thanks. Using \clearlist{address} did not work. Here is a MWE as requested by gernot followed by an entry in the next comment. Clearing the url works. :\documentclass[a4,british,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\usepackage[notes,backend=biber,hyperref=false,giveninits=true]{biblatex-chicago}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{address}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{address}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{url}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{url}}

\addbibresource{/Users/fabrec/Dropbox/LATEX/texmf/bibtex/library.bib}

Comment: @book{Gardner2018a,
 address = {Oxford},
 author = {Gardner, John},
 date-added = {2020-06-30 12:45:55 +0100},
 date-modified = {2021-03-16 13:34:27 +0000},
 publisher = {Oxford University Press},
 shorttitle = {From Personal Life to Private Law},
 title = {From Personal Life to Private Law},
 url = {https://oxford.universitypressscholarship.com/view/10.1093/oso/9780198818755.001.0001/oso-9780198818755},
 year = {2018}}

Comment: Consider accepting and upvoting the provided answer (it apparently was helpful for you) - this is common on this site.

Comment: Plus, the MWE normally goes to the body of the question and not in a comment! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two issues here

- `address` is just a convenience alias for BibTeX compatibility. Internally the field is called `location` (`address` is automatically converted to `location` by Biber), so if you want to delete the field on the `biblatex` side, you need to delete `location` and not `address`;
- `location` (`address`) is a list and not a normal field, so you need to use `\clearlist` instead of `\clearfield` (`biblatex` has three field types: normal fields, lists and name lists, each of those types has its own `\clear...` command: `\clearfield`, `\clearlist`, `\clearname`, you can look up the type of a field in [the `biblatex` documentation, §2.2.2 *Database Guide* > *Entry Fields*](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)).

So

```
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{location}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearlist{location}}
```

would work.

In this case, however, I think that the `\clearfield`/`\clearlist` approach is inferior to other approaches to delete fields.

Either use a Biber sourcemap (which comes in before the `address`->`location` remapping and thus needs to delete `address` and `location`)

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[notes, backend=biber, giveninits=true]{biblatex-chicago}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=month, null]
      \step[fieldset=address, null]
      \step[fieldset=location, null]
      \step[fieldset=doi, null]
      \step[fieldset=url, null]
      \step[fieldset=isbn, null]
      \step[fieldset=number, null]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Gardner2018a,
  address   = {Oxford},
  author    = {Gardner, John},
  publisher = {Oxford University Press},
  title     = {From Personal Life to Private Law},
  doi       = {10.1093/oso/9780198818755.001.0001}, 
  year      = {2018},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,Gardner2018a}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Gardner, J. From Personal Life to Private Law. Oxford University Press, 2018.]

Or delete the fields when they are read from the `.bbl` file with `\DeclareFieldInputHandler`.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[notes, backend=biber, giveninits=true]{biblatex-chicago}

\DeclareFieldInputHandler{month}{%
  \def\NewValue{}}
\DeclareFieldInputHandler{doi}{%
  \def\NewValue{}}
\DeclareFieldInputHandler{url}{%
  \def\NewValue{}}
\DeclareFieldInputHandler{isbn}{%
  \def\NewValue{}}
\DeclareFieldInputHandler{number}{%
  \def\NewValue{}}
\DeclareListInputHandler{location}{%
  \def\NewValue{}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Gardner2018a,
  address   = {Oxford},
  author    = {Gardner, John},
  publisher = {Oxford University Press},
  title     = {From Personal Life to Private Law},
  doi       = {10.1093/oso/9780198818755.001.0001}, 
  year      = {2018},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,Gardner2018a}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The output is the same.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/491887/35864

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! Both solutions worked but I’m going to go with the Biber source map. Feels more elegant somehow. Cecile