# BibLaTeX - Omitting title in citation

Tags: biblatex, citing

I may need some assistance again as I'm trying to omit the title in my citations. The title must not be omitted in the bibliography.

Back in 2014 @moewe suggests to use `\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{title}}`.[[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141822/remove-title-in-biblatex-references)] That post was updated 2018. Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. The functions seem not to be obsolete regarding to the biblatex manual. Nevertheless, using the following code I get "Bock, Strafrecht Besonderer Teil." instead of just "Bock.".

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,%
    autocite=footnote,%
    bibstyle=ext-authortitle,%
    citestyle=ext-authortitle,%
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Bock.2018,
 author = {Bock, Dennis},
 year = {2018},
 title = {Strafrecht Besonderer Teil},
 address = {Berlin, Germany},
 publisher = {{Springer Nature}},
 isbn = {978-3-662-54790-8},
 series = {Springer-Lehrbuch}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{title}}

\begin{document}
Cite\autocite{Bock.2018}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se and thanks for including a minimal document with your question.  The `ext-authortitle-terse` does most of what you want: it will only print the title if there is more than one work by the same author. Perhaps this will suffice?  It seems that otherwise you end up with ambiguous citations, which is presumably never what you want to have.

Comment: That's almost exactly what I want. I'd like to print a short form of the title if there is more than one work from one author. That would be perfect.

Comment: `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{title}}` works as it removes the title from the bibliography but not from the citation.

Comment: `\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{title}}` doesn't work in the example, because the citations don't print the `title` field directly. Instead they print the `labeltitle` field, which is generated from several `title`-like fields (`shorttitle` is given precedence over `title`). In the example the value of the `title` field is copied over to the `labeltitle` field, so deleting the `title` field after that has no effect. You can try `\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{labeltitle}}` for the effect you probably intended to achieve, but that leaves a comma dandling. Alan's answer is much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ext-authortitle-terse` (or `authortitle-terse`) style does exactly what you want. So long as the `shorttitle` field exists in the relevant entries, it will be printed in cases where there is more than one work by the same author; otherwise just the author will be printed. I've adapted your sample `.bib` file to show two different `shortauthor` fields.

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,%
    autocite=footnote,%
    bibstyle=ext-authortitle,%
    citestyle=ext-authortitle-terse,%
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{Bock.2018,
 author = {Bock, Dennis},
 year = {2018},
 title = {Strafrecht Besonderer Teil},
 shorttitle = {Stafrecht},
 address = {Berlin, Germany},
 publisher = {{Springer Nature}},
 isbn = {978-3-662-54790-8},
 series = {Springer-Lehrbuch}
}
@book{Bock.2018B,
 author = {Bock, Dennis},
 year = {2018},
 title = {Strafrecht Besonderer Teil},
 shorttitle = {Besonderer},
 address = {Berlin, Germany},
 publisher = {{Springer Nature}},
 isbn = {978-3-662-54790-8},
 series = {Springer-Lehrbuch}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}



\begin{document}
Cite\autocite{Bock.2018,Bock.2018B}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: That's pretty nice. Thanks! I already tried some stuff with `ext-authortitle-terse` or `ext-authortitle-ticomp` as that woult fit my needs better. But there is a downside in this one. I need to have just one author to be printed. Therefore I use the option `maxcitenames=1`. Unfortunately this leads to exactly the same output for two books when both of them have the same first author because only the first author and no title get printed. That's already far away from the original question. But maybe you have an answer in this case.

Comment: @disjunkt So do you always want to use `shorttitle` to disambiguate those cases as opposed to adding more authors? Because in the latter case you can change the values of  the `uniquename` and `uniquelist` options. But using one author no matter what and then adding the `shorttitle` to disambiguate isn't anything that the styles do out of the box, I don't think.

Comment: I did something wront in the first place. After deleting all automatically generated files an rerunning latex and biber I got a propper result. When two books have the same first author a second autor ist printet. That's not exactly what I was looking for but still acceptable for now. I found the `\ifuniqueprimaryauthor` test. Maybe this can lead to a solution next time.

Comment: @disjunkt You may want to look at the `uniquelist` and `nohashothers` options. I don't fully understand what you have right now and what you want to achieve, but it sounds like those options might be helpful.