# Natbib: don't write the reference's title

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

Simple question: I'm using `natbib` with the [`plainnat` style](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Natbib_bibliography_styles) and I want the references in the "Reference" section to show with *no title*. That is, remove the lines:

[image]

I know I can just go to the `.bib` file and remove the title from each entry, but I'd like to know if there's some way to tell `natbib` to do this without me having to modify the entire `.bib` file.

Comment: You'd have to modify the `.bst` file to tell it to drop `title`s. But I would not do that for all entry types. The LaTeX companion, for example, would be quite a bit harder to find if you didn't know the title.

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/138981/35864

Comment: That solution is way harder than I thought it would be! Also this question looks like a duplicate of that one, so I'm voting to close. Thank you moewe!

Comment: If you are using BibTeX there is almost certainly no way around manipulating the `.bst` file. With `biblatex` things would be quite a bit easier, but I still would not recommend this.

Comment: @Gabriel If you don't want to mess with the .bst file, you could look for other styles which don't show the title, for example A&A hides most titles: https://www.aanda.org/component/content?view=article&id=160