# How to use external bibtex file in Latex2e World Scientific Template

Tags: bibtex, citing

I have downloaded the following  latex template to prepare a paper submission for *International Journal on Artificial Intelligence Tools*:
https://www.worldscientific.com/page/ijait/stylefiles-readme-2e

The file **ws-ijait.tex** is the template to be used as a main manuscript. In the template, they mention that  citations should appear as superscripts and that they can be entered as follows:

```
%%Typeout the superscript citation as:-
%%(1) word,\cite{1,2,3} and word.\cite{1,2,3}
%%(2) word\cite{4}: word\cite{4}; word\cite{4}?
References in the text are to be numbered consecutively in Arabic
numerals, in the order of first appearance. They are to be cited as
superscripts without parentheses or brackets after punctuation marks
like commas and periods but before punctuation marks like colons,
semi-colons and question marks. Where superscripts might cause
ambiguity, cite references in parentheses in abbreviated form,
e.g. (Ref.~\refcite{2}).
...
\begin{thebibliography}{00}
\bibitem{1} C. M. Wang, J. N. Reddy and K. H. Lee, {\it Shear Deformable
Beams} (Elsevier, Oxford, 2000).
\bibitem{2} R. Loren and D. B. Benson, {\it Introduction to String Field
Theory}, 2nd edn. (Springer-Verlag, New York, 1999).
\bibitem{3} C. M. Wang (ed.), {\it Shear Deformable Beams}
(Elsevier, Oxford, 2000).
\end{thebibliography}
```

The described solution assumes references are to be given in a  **\bibitem** form directly in the main manuscript. However, in my case, I would prefer to use an external bib file with entries such as the following:

```
@book{ColBenh:93,
  editor    =   "Fr\'ed\'eric Benhamou and Alain Colmerauer" ,
  title     =   "Constraint {L}ogic {P}rogramming, {S}elected {R}esearch",
  publisher =   "MIT Press",
  year      =   "1993"}
```

The template already provides such a file (sample.bib) so it should be possible to achieve that. I have already tried to replace the following:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{00}
 ...
\end{thebibliography}
```

with

```
\bibliography{sample.bib}
```

and  `book{ColBenh:93`, with `book{1`, but cite{1} will only render a question mark. What is the correct solution?

Comment: The question marks sounds like `bibtex` has not been run on the file, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63875/106162).  On the command line this means running `pdflatex myfile`, `bibtex myfile`, then `pdflatex` twice.  If `bibtex` is being run, then it should be producing a `myfile.blg` which may give additional errors to the log file.

Answer (score 0):

This can actually be done with a little tweaking.

In the preamble insert the line

```
\usepackage[superscript,biblabel,nomove]{cite}
```

This will take care of the superscript.  To remove the article title from the reference list, this will require doing something like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138981/how-to-remove-title-entry-in-the-bibliography-contents/139018#139018?s=88aca8bfb2b540e0be75902479ea6d36)